# byte[] to png file in Android

Tags: android, decode, bitmapfactory

Hi I am working on application which gets .png files in byte stream from server. When I got it I try to make from it bmp and later convert it to .png file, but the following method ( `Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);` ) returns me null.

Here is my code:

```
        byte[] result
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
        try {
            File filename = new File(imageUri.getPath()+name);
            File parentFile = new File(imageUri.getPath());
            parentFile.mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("imageDownloaded", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("imageDownloaded", e.toString());
        }
```

but the img Bitmap is always, null. I uploaded the image as multi part data and it was png file parsed to byte array, but now when i want to retrieve it i get this ugly null. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure you're result object is populating correctly?

Comment: Why are you converting a png byte stream to a bitmap and then save the bitmap as png to file ?  Doesn't sound ok. What you should do instead is streaming those bytes directly to file.

Comment: are you streaming the file into a ByteBuffer and then converting the buffer to a byte array? If so then check the byte order of the ByteBuffer

Comment: I streamed the bytes directly to file, but it wont open so i think something went wrong in downloading the byets, maybe byte order.